# SP2007 using Source token in link

Tags: 2007, development, custom-actions, hyperlink, token

In SharePoint 2007 in some occasions i see that when im redirected to some pages etc, i see a source in query string, and this i can use to be redirected back to the original page.

I've read on msdn that it exists and in url i can say something like:

```
http://url.com?soruce={Source}
```

But the token is not being replaced, maybe it is because in SP 2007 it isn't supported.
This what i have in custom action:

```
<UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/myAppPage.aspx?listid={ListId}&amp;source={Source}"/>
```

The result will be: page?listid=10&source={Source}

Any idea how can I get the source working in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to substitute a value for {Source} with a valid URL to somewhere.
Typically I use JavaScript to do this so I can get the page I am on using *document.location*.

For example, if I wanted to return them to the original page after completing an action I would use some JavaScript in the URL action like:

```
<UrlAction Url="javascript:window.location='~site/_layouts/myAppPage.aspx?listid={ListId}&amp;Source='+window.location" />
```

If the URL is persistent then you could just add it in there obviously.